# Prominent app bar with image appears behind status bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am using a prominent app bar with an image in a fragment.
My style and xml files look like this:

theme.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/DeepSkyBlue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/DeepSkyBlueVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

main_activity.xml (which opens automatically the fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view_tag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.tempapp.pkgFragments.PersonAddFragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_add_person.xml (which uses a layout to prevent redudancy):

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    
    <include
        android:id="@+id/layoutAppBar"
        layout="@layout/layout_app_bar_prominent" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

last but not least, my layout_app_bar_prominent.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout tag not necessary, as we don't use any binding....-->
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height_image_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <!--- contentScrim defines what should "appear" when the bar is not collapsed.
        if not set in this case, the image will remain when bar is not collapsed-->
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:collapsedTitleTextColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_bar_expanded_image"
                />

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
                >

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

So here is my situation:
My aim is that the toolbar image (expandedImage) should appear in the statusbar also.
After researching, some suggested adding the following code in my activity in order to accomplish this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    );
}
```

This works perfect and my image appears in my status bar:

[image: statusbar image]

HOWEVER, the issue I am having now, is that (when i collapse my toolbar), the title and menu icons appear behind the status bar due to the code I add above:
[image: successbar title]
So there is basically no margin between the statusbar and my toolbar, which by default always exists.

If I remove the flag option, I don't have that issue anymore but then the image wouldn't appear in the status bar.

Any ideas how I could solve my issue? I've tried many solutions like:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

but none of the situations worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CoordinatorLayout instead of ConstraintLayout for your activity will probably solve your problem.
NOTE: `android:fitsSystemWindows=true` is (in every subview) necessary, otherwise the app bar will never "fill" the status bar or you will experience some unexpected behaviour.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    >
    
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view_tag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"´
        android:name="com.example.tempapp.pkgFragments.PersonAddFragment" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```